# Which is the default field on which operates Database.Update?

Tags: apex, update, database

I just couldn't find any topic regarding on which Field the Database.Update will operate? I suppose that it will do the update on id but I'm not sure. Am I right?

Comment: It updates on Id field, but if you need something extra, in Database.upsert you can specify external Id field. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm

Comment: @VladyslavKushney I just need to be updated on id field. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right. Database.update works on recordId only.